# Cannot get facebook user data sent to database

Tags: php, ajax, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've got a facebook application where I need to get the user's ID, Name, E-mail and the input value he submitted sent to a database. For a reason I don't know the data is not being sent. I've tried echoing the variables in saveuser.php and I'm getting only the input value. I'm also not getting any errors in the console. My suspicions are that it's something to do with AJAX function:

**EDIT :**

```
FB.login(function(response) 
{
    console.log(response);
    if (response.status=="connected") 
    {
        console.log("You're logged in");
        FB.api('/me', function(response) 
        {
           $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'saveuser.php',
                data: {
                        name = response.name,
                        fbid = response.id,
                        email = response.email
                      };
                 });
        }); 
    } 
});
```

**saveuser.php:**

```
 require('config.php');

if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['fbid'])) 
{
   $fbid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fbid']);
   $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
   $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
   $receipt = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['receipt']);
   addUser($name, $email, $fbid, $receipt);
}

function addUser($name, $email, $fbid, $receipt) 
{
   $query = "SELECT id FROM rkiosk_monster_users WHERE fbid = '$fbid' LIMIT 5";
   $result = mysql_query($query);
   $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
   if ($rows == 0) 
   {
      $query = "INSERT INTO rkiosk_monster_users (name, email, fbid, receipt)  VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$fbid', '$receipt')";
   }
   mysql_query($query);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by using jQuery:

```
  FB.api('/me', function(response) {

   //alert(response.name);
   $("#name").val(response.name);
   $("#fbid").val(response.id);
   $("#email").val(response.email);

  }); 

   $(function(){
    $("#check").submit(function(e){    
       e.preventDefault();  

        $.post("saveuser.php", $("#check").serialize(),
            function(data){
                var jqueryObj = $('<p>You've been registered!</p>').appendTo('#alertbox');
                $("#checknumber").val("");
            }, "json");    
        });
});
```

and by using hidden inputs so I could submit their values:

```
   <input type="hidden" name="fbid" id="fbid"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="email" id="email"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="name" id="name"/>
```

Not the cleanest of ways but I couldn't get AJAX action working.